# Backbone.js connecting views (require.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm a newbie in backbone.js and require.js.
I have decided to use this [boilerplate](https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate). I want to connect two views, like an link click in classic html page. So the code of the first view would be:

```
    // View.js
define(["jquery", "backbone", "models/Model", "text!templates/heading.html"],
    function($, Backbone, Model, template){
        var View = Backbone.View.extend({
            // The DOM Element associated with this view
            el: ".example",
            // View constructor
            initialize: function() {
                // Calls the view's render method
                this.render();
            },
            // View Event Handlers
            events: {

            },
            // Renders the view's template to the UI
            render: function() {
                // Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method
                this.template = _.template(template, {});
                // Dynamically updates the UI with the view's template
                this.$el.html(this.template);
                // Maintains chainability
                return this;
            }
        });
        // Returns the View class
        return View;
    }
);
```

HTML template:

```
<!-- HTML Template -->
<h3>My first backbone app</h3>
<a href="#next">NEXT PAGE</a>
```

and finally the router:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "models/Model", "views/View", "collections/Collection"],
    function($, Backbone, Model, View, Collection) {
        var DesktopRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                // Tells Backbone to start watching for hashchange events
                Backbone.history.start();
            },
            // All of your Backbone Routes (add more)
            routes: {
                // When there is no hash on the url, the home method is called
                "": "index",
                "next": "next"
            },
            index: function() {
                // Instantiates a new view which will render the header text to the page
                new View();
            },
            next: function() {
                // Instantiates next view
                new NextView();
            }
        });
        // Returns the DesktopRouter class
        return DesktopRouter;
    }
);
```

So my question is how to put code defining view NextView into file View.js?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hold a reference to the view object in the router (like your base view) then add on as a property a reference to nextview when it's triggered so they are linked together. Use a map or something more dynamic if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to define an event aggregator which is thankfully very simple.

First create the following object for the event aggregator:

```
define( function ( require ) {
    'user strict';

    var _ = require( 'underscore' ),
        Backbone = require( 'backbone' );

    return _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
});
```

The subscribe and post to the events as follows:

```
Events.trigger( 'video:closeModal' );
Events.on( 'video:closeModal', this.stopVideo );
```

I kinda just grabbed this out of our codebase so if you need more clarification let me know.